# Using a React decorator HOC in the standard composition way

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator

I am using the [Redux Bees](https://github.com/cantierecreativo/redux-bees) library in a project. This library offers a HOC that I would like to use named `[query][2]`.

The example they give is:

```
import React from 'react';
import api from './api';
import { query } from 'redux-bees';

@query('posts', api.getPosts)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { posts, status } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {
          !status.posts.hasStarted &&
            'Request not started...'
        }
        {
          status.posts.isLoading &&
            'Loading...'
        }
        {
          status.posts.hasFailed &&
            JSON.stringify(status.posts.error)
        }
        {
          posts &&
            JSON.stringify(posts)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, it uses this HOC as a decorator. As currently my project doesn't allow the use of decorators, I was wondering if it is still possible to use this HOC in the standard, compositional way.

As I'm pretty sure decorators are just some sugar over standard class functionality, I would think this is possible, but I can't quite figure out how it is done.

I have tried:

```
const withApiData = query('post', api.getPage, (perform, props) =>
  perform({ id: props.match.params.id })
)
```

Then wrapping the export within `withApiData`:

```
export default withApiData(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page))
```

But this doesn't work. Is what I am after even possible?

Comment: Yeah it should work

Comment: But decorator can be applied to more granular level like class method which HOC can't, while hoc can be used with/. SFCs and current decorator don't work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke too soon: it actually works as I described, it turned out that the error stemmed from the fact the HOC is hardwired to make use of a certain redux store key, where I figured that was configurable.

Keeping this here for posterity :)